# Should I create single or separate Kubernetes Specification file?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am working on migration of existing AWS, SprintBoot based system with 50+ independent repositories into Kubernetes. I am preparing a file containing naming conventions for artifacts, docker images and kubernetes resources (e.g. services, deployment, configmap, secret, ingress, labels etc.) for streamlining the process. I am in dilemma over should I use single or separate file for defining kubernetes resources? I know both will work, however I am inclined to preparing separate resource file for better version control and modularity.

Appreciate if you can share your feedback on which one should be preferred? Single file for all k8s resources Or Separate k8s specification file for each resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to go for separate resources files, these would help in managing the resources better, at the same time ensuring modularity as well. Also, most of the deployments in kubernetes are now being preferred via helm charts, which allows a better way to manage the resources file.